# Can I add the User Profile image in a list view or report?

Tags: user, images

We want to show our user's profile image in a list view or report.
something like this (from other apps)
[image]

Is it possible?

I tried creating a formula field, but can't access the smallimage property.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we cannot add show images in list view and profile pictures in reports.

Kindly review Idea link for [list view](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000IkJgAAK) and [reports](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aCqOAAU).

Thanks